# I am implementing file picker on android 11 and when i do uri.getPath() to get path i get it in the form of "/document/msf:1334"

Tags: java, android

While retrieving path from uri i get it in the form of "/document/msf:1334"and hence not able to access the selected file.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_FILE &&
        resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        // the user selected.
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.e("Error!llllllllll", "nullll  " + uri.getPath());
            // String path = getRealPathFromURI(s_activity,uri);
            //Log.e( "Error!llllllllll", "nullll  "+path);

            //fileUri = data != null ? data.getData() : null;
            if (uri != null) {
                DocumentFile d = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);
                if (d != null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "file name: " + d.getName());
                    Log.e("TAG", "file path: " + d.getUri().getPath());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which action do you use for the used intent? Of course the user can browse to the Download folder and pick a file there. Your code does not make sense.

Comment: I am using  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

Comment: Well then i repeat: `Of course the user can browse to the Download folder and pick a file there. `

Comment: yes but i am getting the path in the form of “/document/msf:1334” which is of no use to me to import a file from downloads.

Comment: Then change the subject of your post. And you get an uri. And tell where you want to import the file in.

Comment: my application just wanna read the file from the download folder, its a document file and not able to get the proper path.

Comment: `My application wants to access the download directory and as restrictions from android 11 API 30, I am not able to implement it.` Why is this still in your post? The user can navigate to the Download directory id you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Please edit your post and tell what you want and which problems you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

**Add permission in the manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

**Check for permissions on runtime:**

```
    private void requestPermission() {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
}
```

**Check access to the storage :**

```
checkPermission()
if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
```

**Handle the permission access by the user in the following method:**

```
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
}
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you guys, I will implement  the above

Comment: Accept this as a solution if it has worked for you!

Comment: "android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" should only be used for applications which require complete storage access like antivirus apps or file manager apps. Starting API level 30, this will work on code level but the application will be rejected by play store.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get the right uri and read a file, i hope this can help you. The path that you get is an Uri.

```
import_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            browseButton(view);
        }
    });

public void browseButton(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    try {
      textView.setText(readTextFromUri(data.getData()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStream inputStream =
                 getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```